# What's a good reference for the electrodynamics of moving media?

Tags: electromagnetism, specific-reference

The answer to [a previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6457/2359) suggests that a moving, permanently magnetized material has an effective electric polarization $\vec{v}\times\vec{M}$. This is easy to check in the case of straight-line motion, using a Lorentz boost.

I suspect this formula is still correct for motion that is not in a straight line, but I'm not interested in reinventing the wheel. Does anyone know of a textbook or journal article that derives this $\vec{v}\times\vec{M}$ term? Even better, does anyone know of experimental observation of this effect?

EDIT:
Followup question:
[What is the electric field generated by a spinning magnet?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/what-is-the-electric-field-generated-by-a-spinning-magnet)

Comment: [The Transformation of Rigid Objects](http://panda.unm.edu/Courses/Finley/P495/TermPapers/jesse.pdf) By Jesse Johnson, this study adreeses only part of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To close the loop, Andrew, the answer to your newest question is:

The best and most famous reference about the electrodynamics of moving bodies is

> Einstein, Albert (1905-06-30). "Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper". [Annalen der Physik 17: 891–921](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/andp.200590006/abstract). See also a digitized version at [Wikilivres:Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper](http://wikilivres.info/wiki/Zur_Elektrodynamik_bewegter_K%C3%B6rper).

The English translation, "On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies", is here:

> http://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/specrel/www/

The content of this paper became known as the special theory of relativity. I am just partly joking because for uniformly moving media, the Lorentz boost to the rest frame is still the most natural way to proceed.

Comment: Fair enough, if I'm going to insist I'm interested in non-uniform motion, I should ask a question about non-uniform motion. Here's one to start with: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/what-is-the-electric-field-generated-by-a-spinning-magnet

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer to the uniform motion case, and ask a followup question for cases that can't be addressed with a Lorentz boost.

Answer (score 0):

Chapter VII in Kong's [Electromagnetic Wave Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=cPGepdI-9g8C) contains not only the derivation of the field transformations, but also of the material parameters, the wave vector and the frequency (Doppler shift).